# raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: for sending whatsapp to all conatcts

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run the following code in Python on Windows 7.

I am getting the following errors.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Yogesh Wadhwa\Desktop\whatsapp 2.py", line 41, in 
> group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
> File "C:\Users\Yogesh Wadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime
import time
import openpyxl as excel


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Yogesh Wadhwa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\chromedriver.exe")
def readContacts(fileName):
    lst = []
    file = excel.load_workbook(fileName)
    sheet = file.active
    firstCol = sheet['A']
    for cell in range(len(firstCol)):
        contact = (firstCol[cell].value).encode('utf-8')
        lst.append(contact)
    return lst


targets = readContacts("C:\\Users\\Yogesh Wadhwa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\HNI.xlsx")
#print(targets)

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)
wait5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
msg = input('Enter the message : ')
#targets =['Mona 1','School']
for target in targets:
    x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' +'"' +target.decode('utf-8') + '"' +')]' #.decode('utf-8') 
    group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH, x_arg)))
    group_title.click()


    message = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2EoyP')
    message.send_keys(msg)

    sendbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2FVVk')    
    sendbutton.click()
    time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Comment: I recommend not to scrape whats app because of the high security risks , Because some large organisations have  the highest security. you also have a chance of been banned from whats app.**SO NOT RECOMMENDED TO SCRAPE WHATS APP **

Comment: @AryanMishra I doubt that

Answer (score 0):

When you use explicit waits it will bury problems in that timeout error. You can't tell if it didn't find your object or it took to long to appear.

Few thoughts on your code:

- Your XPath doesn't look right.  You're missing at least a square bracket. Try this instead of the one in the code:

`'//span[contains(@title,"' +target + '" )]'`

- I suggest you verify the value of `x_arg` at run time. Put it in a print so you can make sure that string is as you expect.
- Potentially, your code will only work if you uncomment your `targets` array.
- You're building the XPath in the `for` loop - with no value added. Your dynamically built string won't have anything populated.

Comment: What's the output of x_arg at runtime in the loop?

Comment: Also - please share the relevant parts of the html and i'll be ale to advise if it's correct

Comment: just edited the post to correct order of '" and "' in the xpath...  your original x_arg isn't valid - it'll never find an object so we need to get that out and make sure it's valid and right for the step to pass.

Comment: I have edited full code . please suggest where I am getting stuck. I will appreciate if you can review my code and get it corrected

Comment: I can see you're reading the value from an excel - but i can't see the value you populate. I can see you want to verify it by xpath, but i can't see the html source to verify if it's there. You're getting a timeout because the condition of the wait fails. That can be element not found or not displayed. Please follow my recommendation around printing the runtime value. Do `Print(x_arg)` within the loop, after you set it. Then you at least know 100% what you're code is looking for. If you can share the that and share the relevant html source then i'll be able to help

Comment: print(x_arg)=//span[contains(@title,"HNI Keerat Kohli")]                                                      its prints first contact name

Comment: And does that xpath exist?  - it looks valid  but you've not shared your html source.  It needs to be unique in the page you're looking at.

Comment: And is that xpath found uniquely in your source? - looks valid  but i can't comment on what is in your whatsapp  ... When i look at mine and type in certain names that aren't duplucated i get more than one hit for the xpath

Comment: if you want to just get the first of multiples you can try creating xpath such as (//span[contains(@title,"HNI Keerat Kohli")])[1]    - basically add the () aroudn the xpath and  end in [1]